# Looking for Cloud Browser

Tags: selenium, browser, automation, operating-system

I am planning to run the automation of collection of data from the internet.
The Browser should be working in the cloud network, I want to run it the automation test in the cloud environment. The operating system, browser should be in the cloud hosted.
I want to take the data from the cloud network and post it to email.
Do we have any free cloud hosting provider, so that i can test.
I tried to find the free cloud hosting but could not able to get a good one.
awaiting your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can try out different cloud automation providers like

BrowserStack - https://www.browserstack.com/
SauceLabs- https://saucelabs.com/
etc.